# Mysql get records more then 3 in interval of 1 minute

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I currently developed a cron that runs every 1 minute to analyze the last 60 seconds of the bot records in database, I need to group the conversation ID's that have more than 3 records within 60 seconds in the same url and client_session_id.

follows the SQL I'm running:

```
select
    count(session_id),
    client_session_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id) as talkIds,
    origin_url 
from
    bot_talk
where
    created_date > now() - interval 60 second
group by
    client_session_id, origin_url 
having
    count(session_id) >= 3
```

This query works as I expect, but sometimes my cron service is sometimes down, and I lose those repeated records.

I thought about making an SQL(Cron) at the end of the day to analyze the last 24 hours, and look for the records that are repeated according to the rule I mentioned above?

Currently my database looks like this:

| created_date | origin_url | client_session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-18 11:02:24.0 | https://chat-app.ttttttt.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:02:35.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:11:03.0 | https://chat-app.testett.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:44:28.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:49:36.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:51:05.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:51:15.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:51:19.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:51:43.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 11:51:50.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 12:01:24.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 12:04:48.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 13:40:50.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 15:54:38.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 15:54:45.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 15:55:08.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 15:58:07.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 15:58:11.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 15:59:56.0 | https://someurltestenter1502211068.zendes.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |
| 2021-01-18 16:08:32.0 | https://admin.testete.com/ | znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii |

fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8ce65bad5d39ea85fc5b57d7dc0f729

Comment: Your version of MySQL is **critical** for this question  - you should **always** include it in your questions. Also, please provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8a3c313ab211760643307383f653a1e) with your table structures and data using your server version - help us to help you!

Comment: Hello, my version is 5.7.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I did the following (works for MySQL 8 - window functions used - see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a29cf3343474dd82c049f6c418397856)):

Created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  created_date TIMESTAMP(1) NOT NULL,
  origin_url   VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
  client_session_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it (sample):

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('2021-01-18 11:02:24.0', 'https://ttttttt.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
('2021-01-18 11:02:35.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
('2021-01-18 11:11:03.0', 'https://testett.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
('2021-01-18 11:49:28.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
('2021-01-18 11:50:36.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
('2021-01-18 11:51:05.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii');
```

Then I used the [`LEAD()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/) window function - the syntax is as follows:

```
LEAD(<expression>[,offset[, default_value]]) OVER (
    PARTITION BY (expr)
    ORDER BY (expr)
)
```

The initial SQL is:

```
SELECT
  created_date,
  LEAD(created_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id) AS l_3,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF
  (
    MINUTE,
    created_date, 
    LEAD(created_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id)
  ) AS min_diff,
  origin_url,
  client_session_id
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
created_date    l_3 min_diff    ut_d    origin_url  client_session_id
2021-01-18 11:11:03.0                                       https://testett.com/    znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
2021-01-18 11:02:24.0                                       https://ttttttt.com/    znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
2021-01-18 11:51:05.0   2021-01-18 11:49:28.0   1   97.0    https://zendes.com/ znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
2021-01-18 11:50:36.0   2021-01-18 11:02:35.0   48  2881.0  https://zendes.com/ znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
2021-01-18 11:49:28.0                                       https://zendes.com/ znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
2021-01-18 11:02:35.0                                       https://zendes.com/ znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
```

So, it was noticed that `UNIXTIMESTAMP` (gives the difference in seconds) might be better than `TIMESTAMPDIFF` - (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300380/mysql-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)) - so, in the end, I used (see the fiddle for the result):

```
SELECT
  created_date,
  LEAD(created_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id) AS l_3,
  ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF
  (
    MINUTE,
    created_date, 
    LEAD(created_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id)
  )) AS min_diff,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) -
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP
  (
    LEAD(created_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id)
  ) AS ut_d,
  origin_url,
  client_session_id
FROM test;
```

The final SQL and result are:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
    created_date,
    LEAD(created_date, 2) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                   ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id) AS l_3,
    created_date -
    LEAD(created_date, 2) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                   ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id) AS l_diff,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) -
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP
    (
      LEAD(created_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                            ORDER BY created_date DESC, origin_url, client_session_id)
    ) AS ut_d,
    origin_url,
    client_session_id 
  FROM test
) AS t
WHERE t.ut_d  < 180;
```

Result:

```
         created_date                     l_3   l_diff  ut_d    origin_url  client_session_id
2021-01-18 11:51:05.0   2021-01-18 11:49:28.0    177.0  97.0    https://zendes.com/ 
znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
```

You mention that you have MySQL 5.7 - which doesn't support window functions. You can either upgrade or use various [simulation methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538350/mysql-workaround-for-window-functions) - my advice is to upgrade.

Comment: we're upgrading to version 8 ! thanks for the answer!

Comment: You'll find that window functions are **very** powerful - after a short while, you'll wonder how you ever did without them! :-) They will repay any effort you put into learning them back x 10 times!

Comment: is possible to GROUP_CONCAT(id) ?

Comment: There's no `id` field in the question - you might like to ask another one? I'm giving this one +1 - made me think! :-)

Comment: okay, I asked again

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283859/mysql-get-records-more-then-3-in-interval-of-1-minute-return-group-concat-id?noredirect=1#comment555228_283859

Comment: And I've just answered! :-)  It took me all #$%^&*ing day!