# Mysql get records more then 3 in interval of 1 minute, return group_concat ID

Tags: query, mysql-8.0, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Currently i have this dataset, i need to return grouped ids that are within the range of 60 seconds and have more than 3.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test 
> (
>   `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   created_date TIMESTAMP(1) NOT NULL,
>   origin_url   VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
>   client_session_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   UNIQUE KEY `UC_PRE_CHAT_TALKID_COL` (`id`)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> (1,'2021-01-18 11:02:24.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
> (2,'2021-01-18 11:02:35.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
> (3,'2021-01-18 11:02:03.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
> (4,'2021-01-18 11:11:28.0', 'https://rarara.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
> (5,'2021-01-18 11:11:36.0', 'https://rarara.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
> (6,'2021-01-18 11:11:05.0', 'https://rarara.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0edb1a6098fa1328fde130c369e9adfb)*

something like this:

```
ids     origin_url              client_session_id
1,2,3   https://testett.com/    znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
4,5,6   https://rarara.com/     znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
```

Edit some context:

I currently developed a cron that runs every 1 minute to analyze the last 60 seconds of the bot records in database, I need to group the conversation ID's that have more than 3 records within 60 seconds in the same url and client_session_id.

follows the SQL I'm running:

```
select
    count(session_id),
    client_session_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id) as talkIds,
    origin_url 
from
    bot_talk
where
    created_date > now() - interval 60 second
group by
    client_session_id, origin_url 
having
    count(session_id) >= 3
```

This query works as I expect, but sometimes my cron service is sometimes down, and I lose those repeated records.

I thought about making an SQL(Cron) at the end of the day to analyze the last 24 hours, and look for the records that are repeated according to the rule I mentioned above?

Comment: Unclear. If there are 4 rows, where 3 (either first or last) are within the range of 60 seconds whereas all 4 are not - what three of them are a group? PS. Desired output must match sample data strictly. And sample data must demonstrate all possible data situations.

Comment: @Sealabr To add on to Akina's question, if your example had one more record with `id = 7` with a `created_date` of `2021-01-18 11:10:30.0` it would also be within 60 seconds of record `id` 4 and 6. So how would you choose to group them?...4,6,7 or 4,5,6? In this kind of case would your `id` field be the tie-breaker and 4,5,6 would be the grouping then?

Comment: hi in this case it doesn't really matter which group he will be in, id 7 would be something greater than 2021-01-18 11: 11: 05.0, and would be in the same group as 4,5,6, getting 4,5,6,7

Comment: edited with some context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer - see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eceecfa953771319cab31ac646358ddc). Another answer I wrote to a similar question may provide some clearer background and is a bit simpler - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=45a8ab6dcab7aa95e4ba7eafa184bb80).

All I will say is that it gives some idea of the power of window functions.

I noticed in the comments that there was some debate about what constituted a group - in this example, I have constructed the SQL such that it picks out as a group where all subsequent sessions started within 180 seconds (i.e. 3 mins) of the first - you can change the 180 to 60 (or whatever) yourself.

I've added in some records for the purpose of testing and also added `CONSTRAINT`s to the table definition. It's always best to put as much as possible into the DDL - your database is your final bastion of defence for your data!

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  created_date TIMESTAMP(2) NOT NULL,
  origin_url   VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
  client_session_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT test_cd_url_sess_id_uq UNIQUE (created_date, origin_url, client_session_id)
);
```

Always use named constraints - these provide more meaningful messages than: `... failed... CONSTRAINT xyz_000_43abc has been violated...`.

I populated it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES

--
-- 1 lone record...
--

(1,'2021-01-18 10:30:24.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'), -- XX

--
-- 4 records within 180 seconds of the first one
--

(2,'2021-01-18 11:02:24.0', 'https://zes.com/', 'znkjoc'),
(3,'2021-01-18 11:02:35.0', 'https://zes.com/', 'znkjoc'),
(4,'2021-01-18 11:03:03.0', 'https://zes.com/', 'znkjoc'),  -- **
(5,'2021-01-18 11:04:15.0', 'https://zes.com/', 'znkjoc'),  -- YY

-- 
-- 3 records within 180s of the first one
--

(6,'2021-01-18 11:49:28.0', 'https://rararar.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),
(7,'2021-01-18 11:49:48.0', 'https://rararar.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'), -- **
(8,'2021-01-18 11:50:13.0', 'https://rararar.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'), -- **

-- 1 lone record

(9,'2021-01-18 12:57:24.0', 'https://zendes.com/', 'znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii'),  -- XX


(10,'2021-02-18 09:02:24.0', 'https://rar.com/', 'znkjoc3'), -- ZZ
(11,'2021-02-18 09:02:35.0', 'https://rar.com/', 'znkjoc3'), -- ZZ
(12,'2021-02-18 09:03:03.0', 'https://rar.com/', 'znkjoc3'), -- ZZ
(13,'2021-02-18 09:04:15.0', 'https://rar.com/', 'znkjoc3'); -- ZZ


-- -- XX - Added record > 1 minute from next or previous.
-- -- ** - Changed created_date to get groups within 180 seconds.
-- -- YY - Added record < 3 minutes from previous to give 4 records
-- -- ZZ - Added group of 4 records at the end.
```

It's always worth checking out for edge cases - single records at the beginning/end of your dataset + groups that you want to capture at the beginning and end also! I leave it to you to do more exhaustive testing!

I'll give the results first:

```
rn  st  sids                URL:                Session id: Session start time:            Session end time:
1   2   2,3,4,5             https://zes.com/    znkjoc      2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2021-01-18 11:04:15.00
2   5   10,11,12,13         https://rar.com/    znkjoc3     2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00
```

There's a bonus - you've got the starts and ends of the multiple close-together sessions thrown in for free!

I do have one word of advice - you really shouldn't be using or gathering data as comma-separated lists - SQL wasn't designed for string manipulation and extracting meaningful information and knowledge from such lists is painful - better to have a single atomic datum in a single field - see [`1st Normal Form`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)!

I've left in the various "sub-fiddles" that I used to arrive at the final result - hopefully they'll help you to learn about window functions &c... My own preference for the results would be in this format (see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eceecfa953771319cab31ac646358ddc)  - with one record/session - you can prune as you see fit):

```
sid created_date    st  min_cd  max_cd  f_ts    l_ts    c_ts_asc    c_ts_desc   o_url   c_sess_id
1   2021-01-18 10:30:24.00  1   2021-01-18 10:30:24.00  2021-01-18 10:30:24.00  1   1   1   1   https://zendes.com/ znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
2   2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2   2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2021-01-18 11:04:15.00  1   4   1   4   https://zes.com/    znkjoc
3   2021-01-18 11:02:35.00  2   2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2021-01-18 11:04:15.00  2   3   2   3   https://zes.com/    znkjoc
4   2021-01-18 11:03:03.00  2   2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2021-01-18 11:04:15.00  3   2   3   2   https://zes.com/    znkjoc
5   2021-01-18 11:04:15.00  2   2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2021-01-18 11:04:15.00  4   1   4   1   https://zes.com/    znkjoc
6   2021-01-18 11:49:28.00  3   2021-01-18 11:49:28.00  2021-01-18 11:50:13.00  1   3   1   3   https://rararar.com/    znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
7   2021-01-18 11:49:48.00  3   2021-01-18 11:49:28.00  2021-01-18 11:50:13.00  2   2   2   2   https://rararar.com/    znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
8   2021-01-18 11:50:13.00  3   2021-01-18 11:49:28.00  2021-01-18 11:50:13.00  3   1   3   1   https://rararar.com/    znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
9   2021-01-18 12:57:24.00  4   2021-01-18 12:57:24.00  2021-01-18 12:57:24.00  1   1   1   1   https://zendes.com/ znkjoc3gfth2c3m0t1klii
10  2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  5   2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00  1   4   1   4   https://rar.com/    znkjoc3
11  2021-02-18 09:02:35.00  5   2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00  2   3   2   3   https://rar.com/    znkjoc3
12  2021-02-18 09:03:03.00  5   2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00  3   2   3   2   https://rar.com/    znkjoc3
13  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00  5   2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00  4   1   4   1   https://rar.com/    znkjoc3
```

Or another way might be (again, see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eceecfa953771319cab31ac646358ddc)):

```
sid Session no. Start of sessions   End of sessions Session count   o_url   c_sess_id
2   2   2021-01-18 11:02:24.00  2021-01-18 11:04:15.00  4   https://zes.com/    znkjoc
10  5   2021-02-18 09:02:24.00  2021-02-18 09:04:15.00  4   https://rar.com/    znkjoc3
```

You have the starts and ends and the number of sessions... anyway, that's up to you. Take a look at this bit (easily missed):

```
MIN(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date ASC) AS min_cd,
MAX(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS max_cd,
```

This allows you to have an `ASC`ending and a `DESC`edning list.

This means that you can then do this:

```
WHERE (v.f_ts + v.l_ts) >= 5
```

And the records where this  corresponds **must** be the ones of interest for the bunched sessions.

So now, the SQL, here it is (drum roll, trumpets sound in the distance...)! Go get a cup of coffee to read it - it's a monster (needs pruning - but that's an exercise for the OP and anybody else who's got this far):

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn,
  v.st,
  GROUP_CONCAT(v.sid SEPARATOR ',') as sids,
  o_url AS "URL:",
  c_sess_id AS "Session id:",
  min_cd AS "Session start time:",
  max_cd AS "Session end time:"
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    sid,
    created_date, st, 
    MIN(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date ASC) AS min_cd,
    MAX(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS max_cd,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date ASC)  AS f_ts,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS l_ts,
    COUNT(st) OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date ASC)  AS c_ts_asc,
    COUNT(st) OVER (PARTITION BY st ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS c_ts_desc,
    o_url, 
    c_sess_id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      sid,
      created_date, YYY, 
      SUM(testy) OVER (PARTITION BY testy ORDER BY created_date ASC) AS s, 
      ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY testy ORDER BY created_date ASC) AS rn,
      SUM(testy) OVER y AS st,
      FIRST_VALUE(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY testy ORDER BY created_date) AS fv,
      LAST_VALUE(created_date) OVER y AS lv,
      o_url,
      c_sess_id
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        id AS sid,
        LAG(created_date, 1) OVER x AS lag_1,
        created_date,
        LEAD(created_date, 1) OVER x AS lead_1,  

        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(created_date, 1) OVER x) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) AS XXX,
 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(created_date, 1) OVER x) AS YYY,
 
        --
        -- The IMPORTANT one!
        --
 
        CASE 
          WHEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(created_date, 1) OVER x) > 180
          OR   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(created_date, 1) OVER x) IS NULL)
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END AS testy,
      
        FIRST_VALUE(created_date) OVER x AS f_val,
  
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FIRST_VALUE(created_date) OVER x) AS c_f_diff,
  
        ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_date, LEAD(created_date, 1) OVER x)) AS min_diff,  

        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAD(created_date, 1) OVER x) AS ut_d, 

        origin_url AS o_url,
        client_session_id AS c_sess_id

      FROM test
      WINDOW x AS (PARTITION BY origin_url, client_session_id 
                     ORDER BY created_date ASC, origin_url, client_session_id)
      ORDER BY created_date ASC
    ) AS t 
    WINDOW y AS (ORDER BY created_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                                    AND CURRENT ROW)
    ORDER BY created_date ASC
  ) AS u
  ORDER BY created_date ASC
) AS v
WHERE (v.f_ts + v.l_ts) >= 5
GROUP BY v.st, o_url, c_sess_id, min_cd, max_cd;
```

Comment: Oh my God, I can't believe it, I'm in my car now, when I get home I'm going to test it, thank you very much!

Comment: @sealabr - I "tweaked" the answer slightly - let me know what you think - and think generally - I put a good bit of effort into this answer and would be interested in feedback!

Comment: wow, I just did the tests here and it looks like it's getting a dataset with more than 10k ++ results, I'm looking at more results to see if everything is right, there are some parts that I didn't understand in the sql, as you did in several parties i'm trying to understand how you did, Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll try to understand more, if I can't understand then can I ask you here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't understand this part: WHERE (v.f_ts + v.l_ts)> = 5, I also did a test with this dataset https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b94b384eb5f73c0e6f0fc0aa57adfedc
apparently did not group the session 96tx1w7kd31qr97mz17rd and the interval was longer than 3 minutes, can you help me?

Comment: I've tweaked the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25bf5dce5b332de45f4435100b8aac6a) - search for the string `Vérace` - what else? :-)

Comment: Oh, yeah - `WHERE (v.f_ts + v.l_ts) > = 5` - you want groups of > 3? So, check that result in my fiddle earlier up - to get all the groups with 3 or or more records, the SUM of those two fields has to be > 4 or >= 5... the group with only 3 records has a sum of these = 4 and not above!

Comment: oh great!! I get it now! thanks alot! hhehe